# TypeError: 'Styler' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, pandas

I can access a subset of columns like this:

```
df[[5, 6]]
```

..but after the following line to push text to the left and make it more readable:

```
df = df.style.set_properties(**{'text-align': 'left'})
```

..the same command produces an error:

```
TypeError: 'Styler' object is not subscriptable
```

Is this expected behaviour, or do you need to use some trick now to get to the columns?

Am using Python 3.7.6 and Pandas 1.0.3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Styler does not return a dataframe, but a style object. From there, you should/could use `apply` functions to format your dataframe printout. For example:

```
 # apply style on the columns
 df.style.apply(lambda x: ["text-align:right"]*len(x))
```

Comment: Interesting, it looks like a dataframe both before and after, but before it has type `pandas.core.frame.DataFrame` and after, `pandas.io.formats.style.Styler`. I will make sure to style last and do other operations first. Don't get the impression you can slice it with operations like `df[[5, 6]]` when it isn't even a dataframe anymore.

Comment: I think after your answer, that those style objects are really just for displaying in Jupyter, is not much point giving them handles. If I give one a handle again, will call it 'styled_df' or something so it's obvious it can no longer me treated like a df.